# Extracting Image of the Charts Present in Excel Sheet

Tags: .net, openxml

Is it possible to extract the image of the charts present in Workbook(Excelsheet) Using OpenXML or any other way... 
I am able to loop through all the ChartParts in a DrawingPart.

Also the excelsheet is uploaded on sharepoint.